# I am looking for a similar JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, eval

I am looking for a similar javascript function but without the use of eval. I am triying to create a generic function for simple calculations, with three inputs, two numbers and a sign. The problem is that without the eval the plus signs conver everything into a string, so if I write `return val1 + sign + val2` I get a string back.

```
var calculate = function(val1, val2, sign) {
                return eval( val1 + sign + val2 );
    }
```

Comment: `switch sign { case "+": ... case "-": ... }`

Comment: More like `case "+": val1 + val2; break; case "-": val1 - val2; break`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
  var calc = function (a, b, sign) {
        var usw;
        switch (sign) {
            case '-':
                usw = parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
                break;
            case '+':
                usw = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
                break;
            case '/':
                usw = parseFloat(a) / parseFloat(b);
                break;
            case '*':
                usw = parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b);
                break;
            default:
                throw "Input data is invalid";
                break;
        }

        return usw;
    }

console.log(calc('15.2', '54', '*'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make an object with the wanted operators, test if the operator exist, and use it.

```js
var operators = {
        '+': function (a, b) { return a + b; },
        '-': function (a, b) { return a - b; },
        '*': function (a, b) { return a * b; },
        '/': function (a, b) { return a / b; }
    },
    calculate = function (val1, val2, sign) {
        if (sign in operators) {
            return operators[sign](val1, val2);
        }
    }
document.write(calculate(6, 7, '*'));
```